# Regular Expression to get content between two line

Tags: php, regex

well, i have a big file, there are some contents i needed to be seprated, the contents are located between
 `- - - - - - - - - - [ Ø¹Ù†ÙˆØ§Ù† ]` and 
`- - - - - - - - - - [ Ø§Ù†ØªÙ‡Ø§Ù‰ Ø¹Ù†ÙˆØ§Ù† ]`  , is there any way with reqular expression and php to get those contents?

exactly the format is like this :

```
- - - - - - - - - - [ عنوان ]
في حد اللواط
- - - - - - - - - - [ انتهاى عنوان ]

ومنها قوله سبحانه : ولوطا إذ قال لقومه : أتأتون الفاحشة وأنتم تبصرون أئنكم لتأتون
الرجال شهوة من دون النساء بل أنتم قوم تجهلون ، فما كان جواب قومه إلا أن قالوا أخرجوا

- - - - - - - - - - [ عنوان ]
في حرمة اللواط
- - - - - - - - - - [ انتهاى عنوان ]
في حرمة اللواط
ثم إنه لا شك في حرمة اللواط بل إن حرمته من ضروريات الدين ودل
عليها الكتاب المبين ( 1 ) وسنة سيد المرسلين وأهل بيته الطاهرين صلوات الله
```

and goes on ... thank you

Comment: http://cn.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php#95828 hope will help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code,

```
$lines = preg_split("/[\r\n]+/u", $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
$data = array();
$start = '
    - - - - - - - - - - [ عنوان ]
    ';
$end = '
    - - - - - - - - - - [ انتهاى عنوان ]';
$start = trim($start);
$end = trim($end);
$process = false;
foreach($lines as $line){
    if(mb_strpos($line, $start, 0, "utf-8")!==false){
        $process=true;
    }elseif(mb_strpos($line, $end, 0, "utf-8")!==false){
        $process=false;
    }elseif($process){
        $data[] = $line;
    }
}
print_r($data);
```

**Note:**

1. Due to LTR direction its hard to type in the exact phrase. So I use the trim technique.

[**Sample**](http://ideone.com/HGQCS)

Comment: tnx, but it returns empty array, actually there are to many lines like this on the file

Comment: @HellLord Then post your sample portion of the file please

Comment: i think maybe it should be an encoding problem here, my file is formated with unicode encoding, the language is right to left language , is it OK to use the original text or should i change the format? i really confused :((

Comment: Post the **original content**.  I use heavy regex on a site where chinese, arabic, hindi fonts are supported. SO has no problem with too.

Comment: - - - - - - - - - - [ عنوان ]
مقدمة المؤلف
- - - - - - - - - - [ انتهاى عنوان ]
مقدمة المؤلف
- - - - - - - - - - [ عنوان ]
في حد اللواط
- - - - - - - - - - [ انتهاى عنوان ]
في حد اللواط

Comment: What is your starting line and ending line? Please update your question with this

Comment: I would recommend using an ungreedy match .*? in case you got more instances of this pattern

Comment: @rednaw the earlier regular expression does not need the ungreedy `?`. I have tested it. The problem is with ltr direction.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im I don't really know how to thank you.. it does perfectly work, i just have one another question :-s . i can not get the file content and run this script on it...it does't work this way, i have to copy all contents to the php file and assign it to a variable! is there any way to just read the file content and do the script?( i know the file_get_contents but it does not work that way)

Comment: @HellLord `file_get_contents` should have worked. Try using `$lines = file("/path/to/file", FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);`

Comment: i tried everything, fopen, ur help, fread.... nothing... may be i should ask another question about this issue?

Comment: Yes you can asks another question. But Did you tried file function I specified in previous comment?

Comment: no, did not work :|, iam now just copy paste the content to a variable.